# Chrome mobile device emulator not able to load PDFs

Tags: google-chrome

I was trying to load a `PDF` document in mobile emulator(select any mobile device), it didn't show and kept loading while in the Network tabs, it was being downloaded and shown 200 status code for the PDF document.

While the same link worked in Desktop mode.

[image: screenshot of sample pdf]